# how to append rows as column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

I have two rows as shown below

```
regn_no    date         name  Adress
5001       15 may 2010   A      xyz
5001       13 jan 2011   B      ABC
5001       14 july 2011  C      PQR
```

since regn_no is equal i want to append row with greater date to lower date. 
i want result as below

```
regn_no    date       name    Adress  new_name  new_Adress  new_name2  add_2
5001     14 july 2011   A       xyz      B          ABC        C        PQR
```

please help
thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of VB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do this in Oracle (instead of VB.net), since Oracle comes with built-in functions for this. However, there are some more scenarios you need to think about.

- What if you had more than one change for a given ID? would you like to display it in multiple columns or it is more of a "change tracking" display where you show the old and new value for each change?
- For the latest row (the one on 15th),there would be no new address, so it will be null. If you don't want to pick that up, you need to add one more condition (see second query..)

  ```
  with t1 as (
  select 5001 regn_no, to_date('15-May-2010','DD-Mon-YYYY') date1,
         'A' name, 'XYZ' Address from dual
  union all
  select 5001 regn_no, to_date('13-May-2010','DD-Mon-YYYY') date1,
         'B' name, 'ABC' address from dual)
  select t1.regn_no, t1.date1, t1.name, t1.address,
         lead(t1.name) over (partition by t1.regn_no
                             order by t1.date1 asc)  new_name,
         lead(t1.Address) over (partition by t1.regn_no
                             order by t1.date1 asc)  new_Address
    from t1
  ```
- REGN_NO DATE1     N ADD N NEW

  ```
    5001 13-MAY-10 B ABC A XYZ
        5001 15-MAY-10 A XYZ
  ```

  with t1 as (
      select 5001 regn_no, to_date('15-May-2010','DD-Mon-YYYY') date1,
             'A' name, 'XYZ' Address from dual
      union all
      select 5001 regn_no, to_date('13-May-2010','DD-Mon-YYYY') date1,
             'B' name, 'ABC' address from dual)
      select * from (
      select t1.regn_no, t1.date1, t1.name, t1.address,
             lead(t1.name) over (partition by t1.regn_no
                                 order by t1.date1 asc)  new_name,
             lead(t1.Address) over (partition by t1.regn_no
                                 order by t1.date1 asc)  new_Address
        from t1
      ) where not (new_name is null and new_address is null)
      /
     REGN_NO DATE1     N ADD N NEW

  ---

  ```
    5001 13-MAY-10 B ABC A XYZ
  ```

Comment: The formatting doesn't seem to be working... Please feel free to edit this post if needed.

Comment: Sorry... I have very little experience with vb.net, but is there a reason you want to do this in vb.net only?

Comment: Its ok i got the solution. Thax